# Basic Notation Help

Tags: probability, notation

Taking a robotic planning class and have no stats background. I am just trying to understand what this means:
"What is the probability of the event $R=\{x||x-1|\le 1\}$?"

Can someone tell me in plain words what the $R$ statement is saying? In the problem we are only given that mean$=1$, and variance$=1$. I read the whole chapter this question is based on and could not find a similar instance of this notation.

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand what $\{x\big\vert \vert x-1\vert\le 1\}$ means?

Comment: No that's where i'm struggling

Comment: Do you understand what $\vert x-1\vert\le 1$ means? // Perhaps part of the exercise is to learn how to interpret notation like this, but once you work through what it means, you’re going to see why I find this to be an obnoxious way for the assignment to write it.

Comment: i believe "abs value of x-1 is less than or equal to 1". I should have mentioned before that I have seen the vertical line used in conditional statements in probability functions, but I don't think this is a function so i'm not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: It’s set notation. It means “the set of what’s left of the vertical bar such that right of the vertical bar is true”, so  the set of all $x$ such that $\vert x-1\vert\le 1$.

Comment: So the question would read: "what is the probability that R=x such that   |−1|≤1 ?"

Comment: I don’t know what $R$ is, but my read is that it’s asking for the probability of event $R$, where $R$ is the set $\{x\big\vert\vert x-1\vert\le 1\}?$

Comment: ohh I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is a random variable, the question is asking for what is the probability that event $R$ occur where $R$ is the event that $|X-1| \le 1$.

The condition is equivalent to   $0 \le X \le 2$.

I don't think there is sufficient information unless you make more assumptions.